# Omit hidden files from directory listing with FTP

Tags: unix, ftp

I need to get a file from a remote server and I am using the 
`ls -lA` command to list the files inside the FTP block. However I see the "." and ".." entries being listed as well. Is there any way to omit
them and list only the files that are not hidden?

Comment: The exact behavior and set of supported options for the built-in FTP ls command might vary depending on which server & client implementation you're using.  When I tried it just now, "." and ".." weren't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP protocol has no way to control what files the server includes to the listing.

Having that said, many servers do actually support a non-standard `-a` switch to *show* hidden files. And indeed by default most FTP servers *do not show* hidden files neither the `.` and `..` by default. You have to enforce it using `-a`.

But if your server does show the hidden files, I'm afraid there's no way to force it not to show them, from a client side. Though there can be a server-side configuration option for this, but we do not know what FTP server you are using.

Generally, if you need to do any kind of filtering, you have to do it locally after retrieving a complete directory listing.

For example:

```
grep -v ^.+$ listing.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably by *the files that are not hidden* you mean the entries not starting with `.`; to list only those, just omit the `A` and try `ls -l`.